# How to make OpenGL camera moving in SFML by mouse move

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I've good working (this may be important) FPS camera module in my "Game Engine". Now I'm using it with WASD and Up/Down/Left/Right. I want to add possibility to move camera by mouse. It's my code I've written:

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved)
{
    static glm::vec2 lastPos;
    glm::vec2 mousePos(event.mouseMove.x, event.mouseMove.y);
    glm::vec2 delta(lastPos - mousePos);
    delta *= -0.01;
    cam->addRotation(delta);

    sf::Vector2i center(parentWnd->getSFMLWindow()->getSize().x/2, parentWnd->getSFMLWindow()->getSize().y/2);
    lastPos.x = center.x;
    lastPos.y = center.y;

    sf::Mouse::setPosition(center, *parentWnd->getSFMLWindow());
}
```

How can I get moving my camera without cursor moving on the screen? It's working few seconds and camera locks (so I can't mouse move then I must kill process). I'd rather get event of mouse move not mouse position but SFML doesn't support that.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this problem myself. Here's code:

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved) {
    static glm::vec2 lastMousePos;
    glm::vec2 mousePos(event.mouseMove.x, event.mouseMove.y);

    glm::vec2 deltaPos(mousePos - lastMousePos);
    const float mouseSensitivity = 0.1f;
    deltaPos *= mouseSensitivity;
    deltaPos.y *= -1;
    cam->addRotation(deltaPos);

    sf::Window const& sfWindow = *parentWnd->getSFMLWindow();
    auto windowSize = sfWindow.getSize();

    uint32_t maxMousePosRadius = glm::min(windowSize.x, windowSize.y) / 3;
    glm::vec2 windowCenter(windowSize.x / 2, windowSize.y / 2);

    if (glm::length(mousePos - windowCenter) > maxMousePosRadius) {
        sf::Mouse::setPosition(sf::Vector2i((int)windowCenter.x, (int)windowCenter.y), sfWindow);
        lastMousePos = windowCenter;
    }
    else {
        lastMousePos = mousePos;
    }
}
```